# MailKit gets an SslHandshakeException with LetsEncrypt SSL certificates

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, mailkit, dovecot

I have a server (Centos 7) setup to be used as mail server. Using postfix/dovecot/opendkim/opendmarc.. 
It works as it should, users are able to connect their emails using gmail for example. Able to send and receive mail.

Also when I use MailKit and test my .NET Core application from my home pc MailKit connects fine and the emails are send.

However, when I deploy the application to my server MailKit fails to connect.

If I look in the logs I see the following

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[4486]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/submission/smtpd[4486]: match_hostaddr: MY_SERVER_IP ~? 127.0.0.1/32
postfix/submission/smtpd[4486]: match_hostname: unknown ~? MY_SERVER_IP/32
postfix/submission/smtpd[4486]: match_hostaddr: MY_SERVER_IP  ~? MY_SERVER_IP/32
postfix/submission/smtpd[4486]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[MY_SERVER_IP]
```

But if I look a bit higher in the logs I see

```
Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[MY_SERVER_IP]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
```

My MailKit (which works fine from outside of the server):

```c
using (SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    await emailClient.ConnectAsync(emailConfiguration.SmtpServer, emailConfiguration.SmtpPort, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");  

    await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync(emailConfiguration.SmtpUsername, emailConfiguration.SmtpPassword);
    await emailClient.SendAsync(message);

    await emailClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

edit:
The exception from MailKit (certificate is proper and not self-signed):

```
MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: • The server certificate has the following errors:
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: • unable to get certificate CRL
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: • The root certificate has the following errors:
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: • unable to get certificate CRL
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: • unable to get local issuer certificate
May 19 16:07:37 domain.com NETCoreApp[4452]: ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Comment: FWIW, `emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");` has not been necessary since MailKit 2.0

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unable to get certificate CRL` error sounds like SslStream was unable to get the CRL, perhaps because the CRL server is unreachable for some reason.

You could try adding `emailClient.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;` before the ConnectAsync to check if that's the issue.

The other error, `unable to get local issuer certificate`, might be because the server that MailKit is running on doesn't have the Root CA certificate in its X509Store but your home PC does.

Update:

The problem is that LetsEncrypt SSL certificates do not include a CRL location which means that certificate revocation checks will fail.

To bypass this, you need to set `client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;` before connecting.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The certificate on my server is installed with Letsencrypt's certbot, it should be good since I don't have browsers (and gmail) complaining. It might be worth a try to turn it off tho. 

However, I think, because MailKit tries to connect to the same server from inside.. that there is something going wrong with firewall/rights. 
I haven't tried your answer yet, but found a solution. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that LetsEncrypt SSL certificates do not include a CRL server location which causes SslStream to fail to validate them.

Comment: You need to specify `client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;`

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Didn't know this. Turning that option off makes sense then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### I have the same problem on ubuntu 20.04 with .NET core 3.1

and after 3 hours of trial and error, I finally found the **solution**.
I've just ignored the `Certificate Validation CallBack`.

```cs
using var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("smtp.log"));
client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
client.Connect("your.smtp.host", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
```

I hope this would be helpful :)

Comment: This is a security risk as all certificate validation is disabled. It makes a man-in-the-middle attack possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which works but isn't my preferred method since I wanted to be able to use MailKit for more that just my own server (make it configurable from within the app itself)

I came to the solution because I thought it had to do with some internal traffic going wrong..

By using the old **SmtpClient** from *System.Net.Mail* I was able to use the **DefaultCredentials**.

```js
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1"))
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(emailMessage.FromAddress.Address, emailMessage.FromAddress.Name);

    foreach (IEmailAddress emailAddress in emailMessage.ToAddresses)
    {
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailAddress.Address, emailAddress.Name);

        MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to)
        {
            Subject = emailMessage.Subject,
            Body = emailMessage.Content
        };

        await client.SendMailAsync(email);
    }
}
```